# Formatting dates from Document Properties

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I have a document that holds various dates in document properties eg Approval Date = 01/01/2016 These are stored as type=date.

I want to insert these as Quick Part fields in different formats in different parts of the document.

So, on the Title page, it might display as 1 January 2016, but in the footer it would be 01/01/2016.

I think the the answer probably revolves around a formula field type based on {DOCTYPE "Approval Date"} but it's not the best documented feature and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, inserting a field is the way to go. You can then control the field's output format using formatting switches.

For example, this code:

`DOCPROPERTY  CreateTime \@ "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy"`

Will output something like this:

`Thursday, September 15, 2016`

You can read more about formatting switches [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-and-format-field-codes-in-Word-2010-7e9ea3b4-83ec-4203-9e66-4efc027f2cf3#bm9).

Comment: That's what I was looking for - Thanks. It was the \@ that I couldn't find. That and the odd thing that it only seems to be editable in Alt-F9